# orthogonal projection in the Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $S$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, and $p_S$ be the orthogonal projection function onto $S$. I would like to know why $\forall u \in H$, $\|u\| = \|p_s(u)\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by the scalar product of $H$. I certainly know $p_s$ is linear and continuous, but couldn't quite figure out why such equality holds. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean an inequality, because  an orthogonal projection in general maps some non-zero vectors to zero. In other words, the equality you wrote is not true.

Comment: This is not true as stated.  $\Vert p_S(u) \Vert \le \Vert u \Vert$, but for $u \in H \setminus S$ $\Vert p_S(u) \Vert < \Vert u \Vert$.  For $u \in S$, $p_S(u) = u$ so $\Vert p_S(u) \Vert = \Vert u \Vert$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you so much it makes sense

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you for the insight, it makes sense.